# Application names in launcher are truncated, can it be tweaked?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell

After clicking on the bottom left 9 dots icon, aka Show Applications, there is a launcher. I can't find its actual name.

The text under the icons is truncated to the width of the icon, truncating almost every application name, and it's making the launcher very uncomfortable to use.

What can I do to see the application names entirely ?

Comment: It's a bit crazy that they ship a default app launcher that can't be fixed. What the name of the program showing the apps ? I gonna have a look at the source code.

Comment: It's a GNOME extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1071/applications-overview-tooltip/, GitHub: https://github.com/RaphaelRochet/applications-overview-tooltip